# How to control the OverlayFS size

Tags: debian, filesystems, initrd, overlayfs

I'm trying to mount the rootfs `/` of a Debian Buster system as overlayfs because I'm interested in using `tmpfs` for the `/upper` directory. My idea is to use this to preserve the root filesystem integrity by making it fake-writable. I know there are a few packages intended to do this, like `fsprotect` and `bilibop-lockfs`, however I thin the former one is maybe a little outdated and the latter one seems to be more promising, but both use `aufs` and I'd like to learn about `initrd` and this early user space and the Linux booting process, maybe in a future I'll consider to try `bilibop-lockfs`.

Anyway ... [my script](https://gist.github.com/jfernandz/bfb1285114c136ac2b86320cb06c3904#file-toggle-overlayfs) is based on the current [raspi-config](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config) script; as you can see I'm basically adding [the very same script](https://gist.github.com/jfernandz/bfb1285114c136ac2b86320cb06c3904#file-toggle-overlayfs-L42) as an `initramfs` module and rebuilding, then this module is being triggered when `boot=overlay` is passed as a kernel command line parameter. This script apparently does the work of mounting the rootfs as an overlayfs, however ... I'm having problems with the following; as you can see in the `df -h` output, it shows the size is just `3.9G`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           781M   17M  764M   3% /run
overlay         3.9G  1.2G  2.7G  30% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk1p2  236M   96M  123M  44% /boot
/dev/mmcblk1p1  511M  5.2M  506M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/mmcblk0p1   58G  811M   54G   2% /data
tmpfs           781M     0  781M   0% /run/user/1001
```

And some programs are having problems with this size because when they are running a while, they start to print "no left space on the device" in the journal logs. My question is ... what's specifying this size? I cannot see anything about the size in the `overlay` script. Could I set a bigger size to give a wider margin for those programs?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't realized that you can choose a specific size in the mountoptions when you are mounting a tmpfs; from the [tmpfs manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html):

```
Mount options
       The tmpfs filesystem supports the following mount options:

       size=bytes
              Specify an upper limit on the size of the filesystem.  The
              size is given in bytes, and rounded up to entire pages.

              The size may have a k, m, or g suffix for Ki, Mi, Gi
              (binary kilo (kibi), binary mega (mebi), and binary giga
              (gibi)).

              The size may also have a % suffix to limit this instance
              to a percentage of physical RAM.

              The default, when neither size nor nr_blocks is specified,
              is size=50%.
```

So replacing the [line 86 into my script](https://gist.github.com/jfernandz/bfb1285114c136ac2b86320cb06c3904#file-toggle-overlayfs-L86) with this:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=100% tmpfs /upper
```

The system doesn't report problems with the free space anymore.